# Python Exception: index out of range while debuging the code c++ with support for stl with gdb

Tags: c++, python, exception, gdb, g++

I have a code:

```
#include <list>

int f(std::list<int>& l)
{
    l.clear();
    int i = 0;
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::list<int> l;
    int i = f(l);
    i++;  
}
```

I build it in 3 ways:

1. g++ -g -o main1 ../main1.cpp
2. g++ -g -o main1 -O1 ../main1.cpp
3. g++ -g -o main1 -O2 ../main1.cpp

I debug it with gdb (GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5.1) and when I step into int f(std::list& l) I get such output:

```
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.IndexError'> list index out of range:
(gdb) Python Exception <type 'exceptions.IndexError'> list index out of range:
```

Here is my gdb session:

```
(gdb) bre main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400603: file ../main1.cpp, line 11.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/mhd/Texts/Programming/Programms/Exercises/Linux/BruceMolayUnixLinux/Exercises/2/Head/Debug/main1 
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
(gdb) n
(gdb) n
(gdb) s
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.IndexError'> list index out of range: 
(gdb) Python Exception <type 'exceptions.IndexError'> list index out of range: 
q

Debugger finished
```

How can I prevent this exception? Why have the exception thrown?

Comment: It seems that some gdb python plugin to display the content of the list is crashing

Comment: Looks like this is already reported bug http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53477

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this exception by disabling the pretty printer in question.  See "help disable pretty-printer".